# CNN logarithmic path length

Tags: cnn, rnn

> Path length between positions can be logarithmic when using dilated convolutions, left-padding for text

Could anyone elaborate on the above statement quoted from [CNN and RNN comparisons](https://mchromiak.github.io/articles/2017/Sep/12/Transformer-Attention-is-all-you-need/#tldr) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Often times in text data it is useful to model long-range patterns. Dilated convolutions are a type of convolution that “inflate” the kernel by inserting holes between the kernel elements is helpful in finding long-range patterns. This increases the computational complexity logarithmic compared to conventional convolutions.